# is there a way to get specific index of multiple lists

Tags: python

I'm trying to find out how I can get a specific index from multiple lists.

When I print these lists out onto the console, this is what it shows:

```
['Sep', '8', '2007', 'Honda', 'Civic', 'EX', 'sedan', 'CLEAN', 'TITLE', '$1,999', '(Flushing)']

['Sep', '8', 'CHEVROLET', 'SILVERADO', '2500', 'NO', 'RESERVE', '33K', 'MILES', '$1,400']

['Sep', '8', '2007', 'Chrysler', 'Town', 'and', 'Country', '$1,000', '(McGinley', 'Square)']

['Sep', '8', '2003', 'Hyundai', 'Elantra', '$1,600']

['Sep', '8', 'We', 'buy', 'cars', 'for', 'cash', '$2,000', '(Upper', 'East', 'Side)']
```

I'm still a beginner when it comes to python so I don't know if there's a way to get all the indexes where it shows the costs.

Comment: Which specific index are you trying to get? The one with the dollar sign? It would probably be easier to join each list into a string and use regex to extract it, rather than figuring out which index of which list starts with the dollar sign.

Comment: Have you tried writing some code? Share it in your question and we will try to help you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a list `l` and the cost items always start with "$" you can loop over the list and add the indices to your result list.

```
indices = []
for i in range len(l):
    if l[i].startswith("$"):
        indices.append(i)
```

By calling the `startswith` function you can check if the String List Element starts with a certain character.
At the end, all indices where the element starts with "$" are as elements in `indices`

Answer (score 0):

Or using regular expressions:

```
id=[i for i, item in enumerate(arr) if re.search('^\$', item)]
```

where `arr` is any of those lists.